# ¿Como pasar un DropDownList Value de una vista a un controlador mediante ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

Estoy aprendiendo sobre ASP.NET Core y tenggo algunos dias atoroado en lo siguiente ojala me pudieran ayudar.

En mi controlador tengo Lo siguiente`

```
 public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
 {
      ViewData["FiltroActual"] = searchString;

      var viewmodel = new ProductoCategoria(); //collecion de dos entidades para poder pasar dos viewmodels a la vista

      viewmodel.Productos = from p in _context.Producto
                           select p;

      viewmodel.Categorias = from c in _context.Categoria
                              select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            viewmodel.Productos = viewmodel.Productos.Where(s => 
                   s.Titulo.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

En la vista tengo lo siguiente

```
model VendoTest1.Models.ProductoIndexData
<form asp-action="Index" method="get" >
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding:0px 8px 0px 0px;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categorias, new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "IdCategoria", "Nombre"), "-Categoria-")
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <input id="input-buscar-principal" class="col-xs-11" type="text" name="searchString" placeholder="que estas buscando?..." value="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

¿Como puedo enviar el valor id del dropdownlist al controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Te doy un ejemplo

En el Controlador

```
 public IActionResult Index(string Descripcion)
 {
 ...More code
 }
```

Y en la View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AquiElNombreDelControlador", new {},FormMethod.Get))
  {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categorias.Descripcion, new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "Descripcion", "Descripcion"), "-Categoria-")
  }
```

Espero que eso te ayude

Comment: Efectivamente Robert pero ahora tengo el siguiete problema en el helper DropDownList no puedo indicar el nombre del elemento de la forma como lo dices   (o almenos no se como hacerlo) "model => model.Categorias.Descripcion" porque mi view moodel nos una entidad comun sino una coleccion de dos entidades (Categorias y Productos). Es decir el intelisence no me da opcion de poner "model.Categorias.IdCategoria" y si lo hago me dice que: "Categoria no tiene una definicion para IdCategoria" Como puedo acceder a la propiedad Categoria tratandose de una coleccion de dos models?

Comment: Prueba con esto
@Html.DropDownList("Descripcion", new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "Descripcion", "Descripcion"))

Answer (score 0):

Segun puedo observar, El action que ejecutas es el `Index`, en el `asp-action` le estas diciendo que vaya al `index` al dar submit, y el action `Index` es este:

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
 {
      ViewData["FiltroActual"] = searchString;

      var viewmodel = new ProductoCategoria(); //collecion de dos entidades para poder pasar dos viewmodels a la vista

      viewmodel.Productos = from p in _context.Producto
                           select p;

      viewmodel.Categorias = from c in _context.Categoria
                              select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            viewmodel.Productos = viewmodel.Productos.Where(s => 
                   s.Titulo.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

**Que es el mismo `action` que ejecuta la vista.**

Seguro que estas apuntando al action indicado? Estas haciendo una llamada circular, osea estas haciendo que la vista se llame a si misma.

Pero si lo que quieres es enviar el id de la categoria, has esto:

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString, int? categorias)
 {
      ViewData["FiltroActual"] = searchString;

      var viewmodel = new ProductoCategoria(); //collecion de dos entidades para poder pasar dos viewmodels a la vista

      viewmodel.Productos = from p in _context.Producto
                           select p;

      viewmodel.Categorias = from c in _context.Categoria
                              select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            viewmodel.Productos = viewmodel.Productos.Where(s => 
                   s.Titulo.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

Cuando le hagas submit, entonces el action recibira el id de categorias.

Comment: Creo que tengo una idea mas clara del problema. La situacion es que estoy utilizando como mi viewmodel una collecion (ProductoIndexData) con dos con dos entidades o viewmodels (Categoria y productos) y, en el heleper dropdownlist hago lo siguiente: "model => model.Categorias" porque no puedo (o al menos no se como hacerlo) de la siguiente manera "Categorias.IdCategoria" de tal forma que el enlace se haga correctamente. Entonces mi pregunta ahora es como puedo indicar en el helper algo como esto "model.Categorias.IdCategorias" o cual es la forma de hacerlo cuando el view model es una coleccion?